# Why do I get an error when running mysqld in a virtualenv?

Tags: python, mysql, virtualenv, mysql-python, virtualenvwrapper

When I run `mysqld` in my virtualenv I get an error and abort message.

```
(nettuts)sez@sez-laptop:~/.virtualenvs$ mysqld
111220 15:22:59 [Warning] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/sez-laptop.lower-test
111220 15:22:59 [Warning] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/sez-laptop.lower-test
mysqld: Can't change dir to '/var/lib/mysql/' (Errcode: 13)
111220 15:22:59 [ERROR] Aborting

111220 15:22:59 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

First I tried installing MySQL-python with

```
pip install -E default/ MySQL-python
```

and that gave me

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): '
MySQL-python in ./default/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Cleaning up...
```

then when I checked to see if it was installed it showed it was not

```
(nettuts)sez@sez-laptop:~/.virtualenvs$ pip freeze
Django==1.3.1
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

I then decided to install it with `pip install MySQL-python` and it installed just fine cause it showed

```
(nettuts)sez@sez-laptop:~/.virtualenvs$ pip freeze
Django==1.3.1
MySQL-python==1.2.3
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

**How can I make `MySQL-python` run fine in a virtualenv?**

**UPDATE**
When I run `sudo invoke-rc.d mysql start` this is what I get

```
(nettuts)sez@sez-laptop:~/.virtualenvs/nettuts$ sudo invoke-rc.d mysql start
Rather than invoking init scripts through /etc/init.d, use the service(8)
utility, e.g. service mysql start

Since the script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an
Upstart job, you may also use the start(8) utility, e.g. start mysql
```

Then when I follow the direction to run `start mysql` this is what I get

```
(nettuts)sez@sez-laptop:~/.virtualenvs/nettuts$ sudo start mysql
start: Job is already running: mysql
```

**So what is really going on here?**

Comment: mysqld is already running. You don't need to invoke it again. That's what's going on.

Comment: @FrancisAvila right on. yeah when I run `ps aux | grep mysql` I see `/usr/sbin/mysqld` printed at the end of the first line.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't have anything to do with Python and virtualenv. Your mysqld isn't configured to properly run under a normal user's privileges - it needs to be invoked using your distributions normal service startup mechanism (for instance `sudo invoke-rc.d mysql start` on Ubuntu).

Comment: @DavidKHess I posted the results of running `sudo invoke-rc.d mysql start` Not sure what they mean.

Answer (score 0):

you need root priviledges:

try with sudo before the command ( if your system support sudo users http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo )

otherwhise try looging as root first with the command **`su`**

Comment: when i run `sudo mysqld` my command line cursor jumps to the beginning of a blank line, just blinks there for like a minute or less and nothing happens.

Comment: what distribution do you use?
you may try "sudo su" and after insert the root password.
after run your command

Comment: maybe since as i read is already running you can try to reboot and log in as a root on the system...